# Adjusting last iteration in a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration

I have a question and answer forum. A user may browse responses to questions and promote them if they wish. The code below outputs the different users that have promoted a given question - the users are in the array '$promoters' that is returned from the line $promoters = Promotion::find_all_promotions_for_response($response->response_id); . The foreach loop then goes through each and outputs them, styles by the css class "promoter list". Problem is this.....if I have one promoter I just want their name outputed (no problem with this). But if I have many I want to put a comma between each name and then none after the last name in the foreach loop. Straightforward problem but I failed to achieve this....I tried to add a count($promoters) line in an elseif condition so that if the array $promoters has more than one value, then it outputs the users fullname and then a comma, but of course the last name also has a comma after it which is wrong. How do you indentify the last iteration in a foreach loop and ask it to do something different with this.....

Many thanks guys...

```
          <?php 
          $promoters = Promotion::find_all_promotions_for_response($response->response_id);
              if(!empty($promoters)){
              echo "<span class=\"promoted_by\">Promoted by </span>";
              foreach($promoters as $promoter){
              echo "<span class=\"promoter_list\">" . User::full_name($promoter->user_id) . ", </span>";
              } 
              } else {
              echo "";                
              };
           ?>
```

Comment: This is typically done by putting all items into an array and using `join(',', $items)`.

Comment: @deceze Normally, I would agree, but in this case, the comma is inside the SPAN tag. Even if you use `join(', </span>', $items)` the last item wouldn't have a closing SPAN tag.

Comment: use an array, and implode + add first opening span and last closing span.

Comment: @Typoheads I'd argue that the span should probably not include the comma. Since the class is called "list" it seems weird to wrap each individual item in an individual span to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. I added you suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$promoters = Promotion::find_all_promotions_for_response($response->response_id);
if(!empty($promoters)){
    echo "<span class=\"promoted_by\">Promoted by </span>";
    foreach($promoters as $idx=>$promoter){
        echo "<span class=\"promoter_list\">" . User::full_name($promoter->user_id);
        if($idx < count($promoters) - 1) {
            echo ", ";
        }
        echo "</span>";
    } 
} else {
    echo "";                
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is another way to do it using `implode` as suggested by @deceze:

```
<?php 
$promoters = Promotion::find_all_promotions_for_response($response->response_id);
if(!empty($promoters)){
    echo "<span class=\"promoted_by\">Promoted by </span>";
    $htmlParts = array();
    foreach($promoters as $idx=>$promoter){
        $htmlParts[] = "<span class=\"promoter_list\">" . User::full_name($promoter->user_id);
    } 
    echo implode(', </span>', $htmlParts) . '</span>';
} else {
    echo "";                
}
?>
```

Comment: More great suggestions....thank you all. I think the above method is very slick. Stackoverflow is ridiculously useful....